# "add employee" form without page redirect

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

Im sending form data from employee.php to a new_employee.php, new_employee.php inserts the data to my database.
After submitting the form it redirects the user to new_employee.php and let them know if it where successful or not.

What I want is that it clears the form and let the user know if it was successful or not on employee.php rather than redirecting the user.

NOTE! I know that this isnt sql injection protected or anything but i simplified it when i posted it here.
And im also aware that i should use mysqli.

employee.php

```
    <body>
    <form id="add-emp" method="POST" action="add_employee.php">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />

            <input type="submit" value="Register Employee" class="button"  onClick="fun();"/>
    </form>

        <!--<div id="result"></div>-->

</body> 


    <script> 
        $('#add-emp').submit(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             var form = $(this),
             value1 = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
             value2 = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
             url = $form.attr( 'action' );

             var posting = $.post( url, { name: value1, email: value2 } );

             });
         });
    </script>
```

And this is my new_employee.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
     mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****");
     mysql_select_db("****");       

$stmt = "INSERT INTO employee (name, email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
$result = mysql_query($stmt);
     if($result){
     echo("success!");
     }else{
     echo("failed!");
     }

?>
```

Comment: So what of it is not working? You are calling a function `fun()` that doesn't exist.

Comment: I would like to change it up so it dosent redirect to new_employee.php, im guessing the script needs to be changed for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going wrong here. You have a `})` to many in your code and defined `var form` but using `$form`:

```
$('#add-emp').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this),
                value1 = form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
                value2 = form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
                url = form.attr( 'action' );

        var posting = $.post( url, { name: value1, email: value2 }, function(data) { alert(data)} );
 });
```

And with the callback function in `$.post` you can see what happens and get your message (failed or success) back.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score -1):

You almost there, all that is left is to grab the string of you echo in php file, and add it to the dom.

```
success: function(data){
  var div = document.getElementById('#messageDiv');
  div.innerHTML(data);
}
```